# tflite quantized mobilenet v2 classifier not working

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch, depth, edge-tpu

My goal is to convert a PyTorch Model into a quantized tflite model that can be used for inference on the Edge TPU.

I was able to convert a fairly complex [depth estimation model](https://github.com/alinstein/Depth_estimation) from PyTorch to tflite and I successfully ran it on the Edge TPU. But because not all operations were supported, inference was pretty slow (>800ms).

```
Number of operations that will run on Edge TPU: 87
Number of operations that will run on CPU: 47
```

[Depth Estimation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XcNOu.png)

Because I want a model that runs fully on the TPU, I tried converting the [simplest model](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1zjsamXNjQBsbvuR0y5-dDZgTO8XXun4A#scrollTo=6DP3Ig4WXGbu) I could think of, a MobilenetV2 classification model. But when running the quantized model, I get strangely inaccurate results.

| PyTorch | TFLite |
| --- | --- |
| Samoyed:0.8303 | missile: 0.184565 |
| Pomeranian: 0.06989 | kuvasz: 0.184565 |
| keeshond: 0.01296 | stupa: 0.184565 |
| collie: 0.0108 | Samoyed: 0.184565 |
| Great Pyrenees: 0.00989 | Arctic fox: 0.184565 |

Is this caused by quantizing the model from float32 to uint8 or am I doing something wrong? And if it is caused by quantization, how can I mitigate that? The classification example from corral works fine and, as far as I know, is uses the same model.

**Conversion Process**

PyTorch -> ONNX -> OpenVINO -> TensorFlow -> TensorFlowLite

I wrote my own code to convert the model from PyTorch to ONNX and from TensorFlow(pd) into TFlite. For the other conversion steps, I used the [OpenVINO mo.py script and the openvino2tensorflow toll](https://qiita.com/PINTO/items/ed06e03eb5c007c2e102) because of the nchw nhwc mismatch between PyTorch and TensorFlow.

**Downloads**

Depth Estimation Model: https://github.com/AaronZettler/miscellaneous/blob/master/mobilenet_v2_depth_est.pth?raw=true

Classification Model: https://github.com/AaronZettler/miscellaneous/blob/master/mobilenetv2.tflite?raw=true

Labels: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pytorch/hub/master/imagenet_classes.txt

Image: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pytorch/hub/master/images/dog.jpg

**Code**

This code does not require the Edge TPU to be run, but it does require the google coral libraries.
If I use different parameters for mean and std, like (2.0, 76.0), I get a solid result for the dog.jpg image but if I try to classify something else I have the same problem.

---

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from pycoral.adapters import classify
from pycoral.adapters import common
from pycoral.utils.dataset import read_label_file
from torchvision import transforms

from tensorflow.lite.python.interpreter import Interpreter


def cropPIL(image, new_width, new_height):
    width, height = image.size

    left = (width - new_width)/2
    top = (height - new_height)/2
    right = (width + new_width)/2
    bottom = (height + new_height)/2

    return image.crop((left, top, right, bottom))

def softmax(x):
    e_x = np.exp(x - np.max(x))
    return e_x / e_x.sum()

def classify_img(image_dir, lables_dir, model_dir, mean, std):
    #loading lables and model
    labels = read_label_file(lables_dir)
    interpreter = Interpreter(model_path=model_dir)
    interpreter.allocate_tensors()
    
    #load an resize image
    size = (256, 256)
    image = Image.open(image_dir).convert('RGB')
    image = image.resize(((int)(size[0]*image.width/image.height), size[1]), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    image = cropPIL(image, 224, 224)
    image = np.asarray(image)

    #normalizing the input image
    params = common.input_details(interpreter, 'quantization_parameters')
    scale = params['scales']
    zero_point = params['zero_points']

    normalized_input = (image - mean) / (std * scale) + zero_point
    np.clip(normalized_input, 0, 255, out=normalized_input)

    #setting the image as input
    common.set_input(interpreter, normalized_input.astype(np.uint8))
    
    #run inference
    interpreter.invoke()

    #get output tensor and run softmax
    output_details = interpreter.get_output_details()[0]
    output_data = interpreter.tensor(output_details['index'])().flatten()
    scores = softmax(output_data.astype(float))

    #get the top 10 classes
    classes = classify.get_classes_from_scores(scores, 5, 0.0)

    print('-------RESULTS--------')
    for c in classes:
       print('%s: %f' % (labels.get(c.id, c.id), c.score))


image_dir  = 'data/dog.jpg'
lables_dir = 'data/imagenet_classes.txt'
model_dir  = 'models/mobilenetv2.tflite'

classify_img(image_dir, lables_dir, model_dir, 114.0, 57.0)
```

To run the PyTorch model on google colab I had to replace

`model = torch.hub.load('pytorch/vision:v0.9.0', 'mobilenet_v2', pretrained=True)`

with

`model = torchvision.models.mobilenet_v2(pretrained=True)`

to make it work.

This is the code I used to test The PyTorch model on my machine.

```
import torch
from PIL import Image
from torchvision import transforms
import torchvision

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    
def inference(model, input_image, lables_dir):
    preprocess = transforms.Compose([
        transforms.Resize(256),
        transforms.CenterCrop(224),
        transforms.ToTensor(),
        transforms.Normalize(mean=[0.485, 0.456, 0.406], std=[0.229, 0.224, 0.225]),
    ])

    input_tensor = preprocess(input_image)
    input_batch = input_tensor.unsqueeze(0)

    # move the input and model to GPU for speed if available
    if torch.cuda.is_available():
        input_batch = input_batch.to('cuda')
        model.to('cuda')

    with torch.no_grad():
        output = model(input_batch)

    probabilities = torch.nn.functional.softmax(output[0], dim=0)

    # Read the categories
    with open(lables_dir, "r") as f:
        categories = [s.strip() for s in f.readlines()]

    # Show top categories per image
    top5_prob, top5_catid = torch.topk(probabilities, 5)
    result = {}
    for i in range(top5_prob.size(0)):
        result[categories[top5_catid[i]]] = top5_prob[i].item()
    return result

def classify(image_dir, lables_dir):
    model = torchvision.models.mobilenet_v2(pretrained=True)
    model.eval()

    im = Image.open(image_dir)
    results = inference(model, im, lables_dir)
    for result in results:
        print(f'{result}: {round(results[result], 5)}')


classify('data/dog.jpg', 'data/imagenet_classes.txt')
```

Answer (score 1):

EdgeTPU mapping of **`PReLU (LeakyReLU)`** is now supported in [openvino2tensorflow v1.20.4](https://github.com/PINTO0309/openvino2tensorflow/releases/tag/v1.20.4).
However, due to the large size of the model, it is not possible to map all operations to the EdgeTPU. Therefore, the part of the EdgeTPU that does not fit in RAM is offloaded to the CPU for inference, which is very slow. In this case, inference by the CPU alone is 4 to 5 times faster. EdgeTPU does not support **`PReLU (LeakyReLU)`**, so the operations must be replaced. However, openvino2tensorflow v1.20.4 automatically replaces the operations in the conversion process.

- Converted model
  https://github.com/PINTO0309/PINTO_model_zoo/tree/main/149_depth_estimation
- Convert sample

```
docker run --gpus all -it --rm \
-v `pwd`:/home/user/workdir \
pinto0309/openvino2tensorflow:latest

cd workdir

MODEL=depth_estimation_mbnv2

H=180
W=320
$INTEL_OPENVINO_DIR/deployment_tools/model_optimizer/mo.py \
--input_model ${MODEL}_${H}x${W}.onnx \
--data_type FP32 \
--output_dir ${H}x${W}/openvino/FP32
$INTEL_OPENVINO_DIR/deployment_tools/model_optimizer/mo.py \
--input_model ${MODEL}_${H}x${W}.onnx \
--data_type FP16 \
--output_dir ${H}x${W}/openvino/FP16
mkdir -p ${H}x${W}/openvino/myriad
${INTEL_OPENVINO_DIR}/deployment_tools/inference_engine/lib/intel64/myriad_compile \
-m ${H}x${W}/openvino/FP16/${MODEL}_${H}x${W}.xml \
-ip U8 \
-VPU_NUMBER_OF_SHAVES 4 \
-VPU_NUMBER_OF_CMX_SLICES 4 \
-o ${H}x${W}/openvino/myriad/${MODEL}_${H}x${W}.blob

openvino2tensorflow \
--model_path ${H}x${W}/openvino/FP32/${MODEL}_${H}x${W}.xml \
--output_saved_model \
--output_pb \
--output_no_quant_float32_tflite \
--output_weight_quant_tflite \
--output_float16_quant_tflite \
--output_integer_quant_tflite \
--string_formulas_for_normalization 'data / 255' \
--output_integer_quant_type 'uint8' \
--output_tfjs \
--output_coreml \
--output_tftrt
mv saved_model saved_model_${H}x${W}

openvino2tensorflow \
--model_path ${H}x${W}/openvino/FP32/${MODEL}_${H}x${W}.xml \
--output_saved_model \
--output_pb \
--output_edgetpu \
--string_formulas_for_normalization 'data / 255' \
--output_integer_quant_type 'uint8'
mv saved_model/model_full_integer_quant.tflite saved_model_${H}x${W}/model_full_integer_quant.tflite
mv saved_model/model_full_integer_quant_edgetpu.tflite saved_model_${H}x${W}/model_full_integer_quant_edgetpu.tflite

mv ${H}x${W}/openvino saved_model_${H}x${W}/openvino
mv ${MODEL}_${H}x${W}.onnx saved_model_${H}x${W}/${MODEL}_${H}x${W}.onnx


H=240
W=320
$INTEL_OPENVINO_DIR/deployment_tools/model_optimizer/mo.py \
--input_model ${MODEL}_${H}x${W}.onnx \
--data_type FP32 \
--output_dir ${H}x${W}/openvino/FP32
$INTEL_OPENVINO_DIR/deployment_tools/model_optimizer/mo.py \
--input_model ${MODEL}_${H}x${W}.onnx \
--data_type FP16 \
--output_dir ${H}x${W}/openvino/FP16
mkdir -p ${H}x${W}/openvino/myriad
${INTEL_OPENVINO_DIR}/deployment_tools/inference_engine/lib/intel64/myriad_compile \
-m ${H}x${W}/openvino/FP16/${MODEL}_${H}x${W}.xml \
-ip U8 \
-VPU_NUMBER_OF_SHAVES 4 \
-VPU_NUMBER_OF_CMX_SLICES 4 \
-o ${H}x${W}/openvino/myriad/${MODEL}_${H}x${W}.blob

openvino2tensorflow \
--model_path ${H}x${W}/openvino/FP32/${MODEL}_${H}x${W}.xml \
--output_saved_model \
--output_pb \
--output_no_quant_float32_tflite \
--output_weight_quant_tflite \
--output_float16_quant_tflite \
--output_integer_quant_tflite \
--string_formulas_for_normalization 'data / 255' \
--output_integer_quant_type 'uint8' \
--output_tfjs \
--output_coreml \
--output_tftrt
mv saved_model saved_model_${H}x${W}

openvino2tensorflow \
--model_path ${H}x${W}/openvino/FP32/${MODEL}_${H}x${W}.xml \
--output_saved_model \
--output_pb \
--output_edgetpu \
--string_formulas_for_normalization 'data / 255' \
--output_integer_quant_type 'uint8'
mv saved_model/model_full_integer_quant.tflite saved_model_${H}x${W}/model_full_integer_quant.tflite
mv saved_model/model_full_integer_quant_edgetpu.tflite saved_model_${H}x${W}/model_full_integer_quant_edgetpu.tflite

mv ${H}x${W}/openvino saved_model_${H}x${W}/openvino
mv ${MODEL}_${H}x${W}.onnx saved_model_${H}x${W}/${MODEL}_${H}x${W}.onnx
```

- **`PReLU (LeakyReLU)`** to **`Maximum (ReLU)`**, **`Minimum`**, **`Mul`**, **`Add`**
  From:
  [image]
  To:
  [image]
- EdgeTPU model
  [image]
  [image]

Comment: Firts, i would like to thank you for your advice although my main problem is converting the classification model. But i get a subpar result at best with your method.

Comment: **If I try to convert my model with the following command:**


openvino2tensorflow --model_path <path to model> --model_output_path <output path> --output_saved_model --output_pb --output_edgetpu --string_formulas_for_normalization 'data / 255' --output_integer_quant_type 'uint8' 


**I get an error message:**
Please install edgetpu_compiler according to the following website

Comment: If I download your .tflite model and convert it manually (edgetpu_compiler -sad -t 3600 -n 1 model_full_integer_quant.tflite) I get a working TPU model with 131 operations on the TPU and 13 on the CPU which leads to a performance increase of 30% on my machine but the  [output image](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/AaronZettler/miscellaneous/master/depth_est_out_faster.jpg) looks horrible.

Comment: I wanted to isolate the problem, so I first tried to get a lightweight classification of the MobileNetV2 model from PyTorch. However, when I run Colabo, I get an error.

HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: rate limit exceeded.

I don't know what Gradio is, but how can I get ONNX?

Comment: It is the official example" from https://pytorch.org/hub/pytorch_vision_mobilenet_v2/.
I think I had to replace "model = torch.hub.load('pytorch/vision:v0.9.0', 'mobilenet_v2', pretrained=True)" with "model = torchvision.models.mobilenet_v2(pretrained=True)" to make it work.

Comment: I can't verify this because it doesn't work for me anymore. I get different errors. I will update my Question and provide the code I use to test the pytorch model on my machine.

Comment: Export to ONNX was successful.

Comment: I don't know the cause, but it seems that INT8 quantization causes a significant shift in the output. The input data is [1,224,224,3] all "1.0" data divided by "255". Just quantizing to INT8 before converting to the EdgeTPU model seems to screw up the values. My post-processing may be lacking.

$ python3 test_onnx_openvino_tflite.py 
test.npy shape: (1, 224, 224, 3)
onnx sum output: -0.039703369140625
openvino sum output: -0.03968048095703125
tflite sum output(float32): -0.0396881103515625
tflite sum output(int8): -1.663238525390625

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237051/discussion-between-pinto0309-and-aaron-zettler).